# How should a command-line tool use Okta OAuth tokens to authenticate to AWS HTTP APIs for longer than an hour?

Tags: oauth-2.0, aws-api-gateway, openid-connect, okta, aws-http-api

I am authoring a CLI tool that accesses an AWS Lambda-hosted service, accessed via an AWS [HTTP API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api.html) Gateway. The API Gateway is configured to authenticate clients using its support for [JWT authorizers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-jwt-authorizer.html).

The IdP I am using is Okta. If I pass an **ID token** I receive from Okta to the API GW, it is clear how the API GW should be configured. Here is an example token:

```
{
  "sub": "00urlzgj2EXAMPLE",
  "ver": 1,
  "iss": "https://example.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default",
  "aud": "0oarluqjl0EXAMPLE",
  "iat": 1593770403,
  "exp": 1593774003,
  "jti": "ID.vCYIDVfYjcwohRvoP79EXAMPLE",
  "amr": ["pwd", "otp", "mfa"],
  "idp": "0oa1gay7eWJEXAMPLE",
  "nonce": "mynonce",
  "auth_time": 1593770400,
  "c_hash": "m6IADKIwnRdwEXAMPLE"
}
```

Given this, I know I should use the following CloudFormation to define my API:

```yaml
  Api:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          Okta:
            IdentitySource: $request.header.Authorization
            JwtConfiguration:
              issuer: https://example.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default
              audience: [0oarluqjl0EXAMPLE]
```

Note that the `aud` is unique to my application, i.e. it is the app's "client ID" in Okta.

The above works, but ID tokens are limited to a lifetime of 1 hour in Okta and this cannot be changed. I'd like for my CLI to be able to have a token that lasts at least a working day. It also feels like a misuse of an ID token, because this is what *access* tokens are for, right? And Okta allows you to configure the expiry of an access token - perfect! But there's an issue. Access tokens look like this:

```
{
  "ver": 1,
  "jti": "AT.6OrUpPP_OmIPayrEzetEXAMPLE",
  "iss": "https://example.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default",
  "aud": "api://default",
  "iat": 1593771163,
  "exp": 1593779763,
  "cid": "0oarluqjl0EXAMPLE",
  "uid": "00urlzgj2EXAMPLE",
  "scp": ["openid"],
  "sub": "me@example.com"
}
```

This is fine and technically it works, but I'm concerned about the `aud` being `api://default`. Shouldn't the audience be **my API specifically**? Otherwise, what's to stop a user from getting a valid access token for some other client of my Okta installation and reusing it with my API?

The audience is configurable in Okta, but it is at a per-[authorization server](https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/auth-servers/) level. Each authorization server can have many associated client apps, which makes me think that this is not using Okta "as intended". It doesn't seem right to have a 1:1 mapping of authorization servers to applications in Okta.

The [API GW docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-jwt-authorizer.html) say they will check `aud` *or* `client_id`, but Okta specifies my app's client ID in the `cid` field - so that's no good to me here.

What am I missing? Should I be sending the `id_token` to the API GW? If so, what are access tokens even for? And if so, why would Okta limit these to an hour but not access tokens? If I *should* be using access tokens, how do I resolve this generic `aud` issue?

Answer (score 0):

Good question - here is the approach I would take:

**TOKENS**

The id token is private to your CLI tool and should not be sent to the API gateway. Send the access token instead. Maybe it is just that AWS docs refer to id tokens but access tokens are supported also?

**CONTROLLING CLIENT ACCESS TO APIs**

One option is to use audience, though this is often a global value as you've indicated. Another option is to use custom scopes to represent high level access. For example you might have 3 entry point APIs, and the token issued to your CLI tool might have a scope of 'sales', meaning it can only call that API:

- orders
- sales
- reports

**ADD REQUIRED SCOPE TO AUTHORIZER**

Looks like you  should just be able to add a 'scope' attribute to your CloudFormation.

**TRY SENDING AN ACCESS TOKEN**

Okta issue these as JWTs and it should fit with token validation used by HTTP APIs, which is based on downloading token signing keys from the JWKS endpoint

**CUSTOM AWS AUTHORIZERS**

For finer control use Rest APIs and build a custom lambda authorizer for the Sales API that performs these steps:

- Validate the token and expected audience
- Verify that the 'sales' scope is present and reject the call otherwise

**CLAIMS CACHING**

After token validation is complete, whether or not you use introspection, AWS will cache claims in a policy document. A custom authorizer will enable you to include custom data in the claims cache, which can often be useful.

**SOME RELATED RESOURCES OF MINE**

- [Code for a Custom Authorizer](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.serverless/tree/master/src/plumbing-oauth/src/oauth)
- [AWS Lambda Authorizer Technical Write up](https://authguidance.com/2018/12/11/serverless-api-overview/)

**HTTP APIs**

These are new and don't support custom authorizers yet according to [this article](https://medium.com/serverlessguru/amazon-api-gateway-http-apis-with-the-serverless-framework-7be95f305318).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Gary! So based on your answer referring to custom authorisers, should I assume that this problem can only be resolved using the classic "REST API" offering and is not possible with the "HTTP API" offering released more recently? That would be a shame, but not a show stopper.

Comment: Hmm - not used HTTP APIs yet - see updated answer for some thoughts ..